# Search String (Keywords) within all doc files in folder

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to search a string within a set of word documents within a folder then put those results in a listbox.
So far I can search the names of the files and get them to show on my list box. But trying to figure out if it is even possible to search within the files for these key words (Strings).

The search string is grabbed from a text box in an access form

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub searchbox_Change()
Dim FileName As String
Dim Search As String

Me.SOPList.RowSource = ""

    Search = searchbox.Text
    FileName = Dir("\\page\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\SOPs" & "\*" & Search & "*.docx", vbNormal)
    
    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
    Me.SOPList.AddItem FileName
    FileName = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to search a file to see if it contains a keyword.  Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @freeflow sorry about that. Yes, I would like to be able to be able to search all/multiple documents in a folder using a keyword.

Comment: Then there are many examples available in SO.

Comment: I'm searching through them. Was hoping if someone had a quick resource/reference that may match my scenario that would be great. If not I will keep looking. Sometime better to ask since there is also many ways to do things and if someone had an easier way than what I was trying I always like to learn :)

Comment: But SO is a resource of 'last resource'. You come here when you have exhausted all other possibilities,.

Comment: Sorry I must have missed that on the home page. That should probably be in big bold letters.

Comment: Not sure about what type of examples you're searching for, @Deke.  Have you worked out how to search for your target text in one document?  Seems to me the rest of your question hinges on that capability.

Comment: @Hansup you're correct. I just need to figure out the syntax for a find or search into multiple documents and any examples. The general SO and Google search is a set of variations on "vba find string in multiple word documents" done this in SO and Google found some things but nothing that truly fits.

Comment: We may not be on the same page, @Deke. My suggestion is to ignore the multiple documents angle for now.  Focus instead on how to search a single document for your target text.  If you can get that single doc search working, I'm certain we can  adapt your current code to use it in the `Do While Len(FileName) > 0` loop.

Comment: Oh! sorry. I'm having a bit of a day. I have found instances of how to do a keyword search through Word VBA but not through Access yet. I'll try to tailor my search to that criteria and see what I can find.

Comment: I was thinking use Access VBA to create and automate a Word.Application instance.  Like starting with `Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")`, then open your `FileName` there and do the search --- using the same Word VBA methods you mentioned.

Comment: @HansUp that's a really good idea. I had begun to go down that road but then started to overthink it. Mainly cause I kept going back to trying to figure out how to deal with multiple Word docs instead of just focusing on one for now. Gonna give this a try.

Comment: Be aware that if you create an instance through create object you won't get any intellisense help for your word objects.  When developing you code itts much much better to add a reference to Word.  Then you won't end up scratching your head over why your Word enumeration constants keep giving you zero.  Also, if you haven't done so already, you should download and install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and start looking at the code inspection results.